# Is there a working, functional, maintained way to accept bitcoins through a Wordpress site to an Electrum wallet?

Tags: electrum, ecommerce, retail

I know that there is the [Bitcoin Payments for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bitcoin-payments-for-woocommerce/), but it hasn't been updated in over and year and doesn't support the latest version of Electrum MPK.  It only supports Electrum 1.9.8 MPK.

Comment: Are you accepting donations or are you delivering some service or goods in exchange for bitcoin?

Comment: The question is valid either way, but I am trying to setup a commerce site selling goods in exchange for bitcoin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accept Bitcoin over Lightning (much faster and almost no transaction fees), which is a second layer solution on top of Bitcoin.

LNBits plugin for WordPress adds a Bitcoin/Lightning payment gate into your WooCommerce e-shop. The payments go into LNBits Lightning wallet which you can first use the custodial one at lnbits.com and later switch to your own instance of LNBits running on Umbrel (it's fully open source):
https://wordpress.org/plugins/lightning-payment-gateway-lnbits/

Then you will be accepting Bitcoin in WordPress e-shop, without any middleman (fully controlling your keys) and without fees (except tiny routing fees).

Comment: I've been hearing good things about the Lightning network.  This is a great solution.  It took the community nearly 6 years, but it's a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've searched quite a lot for something like this and to my knowledge, the answer is no.

- the bitcoinway plugin you reference was the closest thing to a working plugin that required no middleman.  It used to work with the older woocommerce and the 1.9.8 mpk but it doesn't work at all now with the latest woocommerce version.  It has not been updated in a long time and id say its a dead plugin now.
- the closest thing I've found to replace it was the coin simple woocommerce plugin but as of the latest woocommerce update, it no longer works due to a JSON parse error that I can't workaround.  It does require signup on coin simple but from what I can tell, the API key and biz ID are input to allow you to validate transactions.  Your MPK is plugged in on woocommerce and coin simple never controls the wallet.
- gourl.io is probably the next best thing but they do have interaction with your wallet and forwarding of the funds.
- there is a plugin that works with an MPK that generates addresses with the click of a button.  But its not automated as far as commerce sales go.  The plugin name is "Bitcoin Payments".  https://wordpress.org/plugins/bitcoin-address/

if anybody finds a working plugin without a middleman, please share.

Answer (score 1):

Mycelium Gear works well with Electrum and Wordpress. As does CoinSimple. Each: Money straight to your HD wallet with Electrum - one address per sale. Each has a plugin for Wordpress.

Comment: What is Mycelium Gear, how does it integrate with Electrum and not other wallets, what makes you say "works well"?… Please give us something to work with, not a one-liner without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Blockonomics has direct to wallet [wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/blockonomics-bitcoin-payments/).

- Payments go directly to your HD wallet. All major HD wallets like trezor, ledger, electrum, mycelium are supported
- There are no KYC/documentation requirements, you can start using it using your emailid
- The plugin is also [open source](https://github.com/blockonomics/woocommerce-plugin), in case you want to make changes.